Rust lsp: auto import for rustic-mode broken
Recently (in the last 2 months) the auto import for rustic-mode stopped working; It seems it is related to something in my current project, because if I start a fresh rust project it works again.
My problem is that the prompt for importing things still shows up, but the import just never shows up where it should. toggle-debug-on-error does nothing, and no errors are shown nor messages in the messages console.
Has anyone encountered this before, or has tips relevant for debugging this issue?
I'm using spacemacs-develop and the project in question is no_std, nightly rust.
